# Flutter & firesbase : how can i do a 'contains only from' query

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in Flutter and I'm trying to build an app with cloud firestore as a backend.

I have a list of items in the database that are displayed on the screen, the user selects the items he wants.

And then I want to display all the lists that I have and conatins items from the list the user selected. (like if the user selected ['tree',''sky','flower','table'], and in the database I have ['tree','flower'] and ['tree',''sky','flower','table'] I want to display them).

I tried with arrayContainsAny but it also shows me lists that contains other items like ['tree','sky','orange'].

Is there any way to do it ?

**EDITH** :

if the user list selection is  : ['tree','orange','sky','flower']

and in my databse I have these arrays : ['flower','sky'] , ['tree','orange','sky','flower'] and ['sky','orange','computer']

then what I want to do is display only the 2 first arrays (['flower','sky'] and ['tree','orange','sky','flower']) and not the last one because 'computer' is not in the user list

and the problem with arrayContains is that it displays the 3 lists, and that's not what I want.

Thank you

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a use-case for `arrayContainsAny`. Can you edit your question to show what you tried with that clause and what wrong results it returned?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, arrayContainsAny returns things that I don't want, I edited my question so you can see an example of what I got using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Method. when you get all Items from firestore array then assign that to a list and use that wherever you want.

```
 List<String> myList = [];
   getdata() async{
     await Firestore.instance.collection("points").document('biZV7cepFJA8T6FTcF08').get().then((value){
       setState(() {
         // first add the data to the Offset object
         List.from(value.data['point']).forEach((myitems){
           myList.add(myitems);
         });

       });
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

After Firebase returns your results. You can be sure that those items exist in your database, and when you get them back, even if they have extra items, filter those based on the users input.
This way you we be sure that users won't be filtering items that don't exist or you don't provide. In step 2, perform a second filter locally by comparing lists. It won't be heavily consumptive for your app and it runs synchronously.